# SSL Certificate error when running my SSL site from IIS server

Tags: iis, ssl, browser, certificate

When I browse my website the certificate is recognized and all is ok. Exept if I browse it directly from the IIS server, I get the certificate error below :

```
"The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address."
```

It's a problem for a print funciton, in a background process there is a webBrowser object which navigate to one of my pages to create an image of a View.

Does anyone else already had this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if on IIS you clicked on

BROWSE *.443 (https) . If yes, then it opens with https://localhost and is using the certificate which you have binded to the actual website using port 443.

Common does not match with the certificate as the Url displayed will show localhost but the certificate Common Name  will display a different URL.